# dynamica changing in images from web

Tags: android, image

I want to display images DYNAMICALLY which changes run time in android. i am confused how to display these images. These images will be from web, two images should be displayed at a time on screen.

i can declare drawable array like this, am i on the righ way?

```
  Drawable[] image;

for(int i=0;i<len;i++) 
{
   InputStream is = (InputStream) newURL(url).getContent();
   draw[i]=Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
}
```

How can i do this in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the BitmapFactory class. So you get your Bitmap using:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

When you are finished with your Bitmap you should make sure to recycle it (bmp.recycle()) otherwise you might get an out of memory exception.

Comment: ok, thanks Mark, now can you help me how to change imageresource for imageview for specific time period?